# Create archive webpage for newsletters based on nested array

Tags: php, array, html, iteration

I am creating a webpage for my newsletter archives.  The archives are divided by year (currently there is only 1, but there could be many), then by topic, before listing each newsletter.  There will always be exactly five topics, but the number of newsletters in each topic will vary.

I add the name of the newest newsletter in only one place - at the end of the array. I have a link to the most recent newsletter above the rest of the archives.

This code works fine, but the way that I am retrieving the most recent newsletter seems somewhat hacky.

The newsletters are currently stored in my server as `# segment year`.

```
$newsletter = array(
        "Year 1" => array(
                "First Topic" => array(
                            "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",
                            ),
                "Second Topic" => array(
                            "j","k","l","m","n","o","ab",
                            ),
                "Third Topic" => array(
                            "cd","ef","fo","er","abd","cdf","eee",
                            ),
                "Fourth Topic" => array(
                            "fff","wet","csg","qqq",
                            ),
                "Fifth Topic" => array(
                            
                            ),
                )
        );

$archive_design = "";

foreach($newsletter as $gilYear => $book){
    $i=1;
    $archive_design .= "<div id=$gilYear class=year>
        <!--<h3> Year $gilYear </h3>-->
        <div class=year-content>";
    foreach($book as $book => $segment){
        $archive_design .= "<div id=$gilYear-$book class=column>
            <b><u>$book</u></b>
            <p></p>
            <ul>
            ";
        foreach($segment as $segment){
            $link = "$i ".strtolower($segment)." ".$gilYear;
            $recent = $segment;
            $i++;
            $archive_design .= "<li>
                                <a href=\"http://example.org/newsletter/$link.pdf\" target='_blank'>$segment </a>
                                <hr/>
                                </li>";
        }
        $archive_design .= "</ul></div><!--end $gilYear-$book-->";
    }
    $archive_design .=  "</div><!--end year-content -->
            </div><!--end $gilYear -->";
}
?>
<html lang="en" >

<body>
 
<div id="header">
        <a href="http://example.org/newsletter/<?php echo $link; ?>.pdf" target=_blank> Current Issue - <?php echo $recent;?></a></br>

    <h3>Click on the segment to view, download and enjoy the archives!</h3>
</div>

<div id="archives">

<?php 
echo $archive_design;
?>

</div><!--end archives-->
```

Comment: This question is nearly 1 year old, are you still looking for advice/review on this question?  How are you "archiving" your data?  Is there a database table? if not, that is the first step in all of this.  The second step is generating an auto-incremented id for each newsletter.  When you've done these things, please update your question, and I am happy to offer some additional pieces of advice.  (Alternatively, if you are no longer seeking assistance, perhaps delete this question so as to remove this abandoned post.)

Answer (score 1):

## Structure Review

### Separating Logic from display

This approach works but it would be cleaner to have the PHP code send the data to either an HTML template engine (e.g. [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade), [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) etc.) or to JavaScript where a template can be used to add HTML elements (as I described in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/222122/120114)) using [`json_encode()`](https://PHP.net/json_encode).

Perhaps the hard-coded array `$newsletter` represents data that actually comes from another source - e.g. a database query. If there is a chance that there would not be any relevant data then perhaps the output should reflect this scenario with a message - e.g. *There are no segments available.*

### Means of retrieving the most recent newsletter

> This code works fine, but the way that I am retrieving the most recent newsletter seems somewhat hacky

I agree with this reflection. Perhaps a better approach would be to use a function to pop data off of the end of the arrays - as soon as a segment is found then it can be returned, thus ending the loops.

If there happen to be no relevant segments then the function could have a default case where `null` is returned.

## Code Review

### Variable names, re-use

In the outer `foreach` loop the iterator variable is `$book`, however that is typically an array of arrays, so a more appropriate variable name would be a plural name - e.g. `$books`.

> ```
> foreach($newsletter as $gilYear => $book){
> ```

Similarly, the second `foreach` iterates over that array in `$book` and re-uses that variable name for the index during each iteration:

> ```
> foreach($book as $book => $segment){
> ```

Perhaps a better name for the index iterator variable would be `$bookName`. While the code does not re-use the `$book` from the outer `foreach` it is wise not to over-write variables. Consider the case where access to that variable was needed after the second `foreach` loop.

The same is true for the name `$segment` - in the second `foreach` loop that iterator variable appears to hold an array of strings, so a plural name would be appropriate there as well - e.g. `$segments`.

### Commented header

There wasn't any explanation of this in the description but it appears that there is a section heading containing the year - this is contained within an HTML comment so it would be in the HTML source but not displayed:

> Year $gilYear -->

### Short echo tags

There are two lines where PHP variables are echoed -

> ```
>     <a href="http://example.org/newsletter/<?php echo $link; ?>.pdf" target=_blank> Current Issue - <?php echo $recent;?></a></br>
> ```

and

> ```
> <?php 
> echo $archive_design;
> ?>
> ```

Depending on the version of PHP, one could consider using [`<?=`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) instead of `<?php echo`.

For more information, refer to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694/244085)  and others to [*Is it bad practice to use `<?=` tag in PHP?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/151661/244085).